# Background image is not able to setup

Tags: html, css

[I have done all ways but couldnt find way to setup the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFOD8.jpg)

[image]

I have done many ways to solve this problem but not able to solve it. i have tried all properties of background image but it doesnt works. So kindly help me to solve my document.
I have done many ways to solve this problem but not able to solve it. i have tried all properties of background image but it doesnt works. So kindly help me to solve my document.
I have done many ways to solve this problem but not able to solve it. i have tried all properties of background image but it doesnt works. So kindly help me to solve my document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>welcome to designing world</title>
    <style>
        body{
            
          background-image: url(back.jpg);
          background-repeat:no-repeat;
           
        }
        .container{
          padding: 0;
          margin: auto;
          text-align: center;
          position: relative;
          background-image:url(login.jpg);
          width: 40%;
          height:70vh;
         
          z-index:4;
         
          border-radius: 9px;
        }
          .head h3{
            position: relative;
            top: 60px;
            color: aliceblue;
            font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
            font-size:30px;
            text-transform: capitalize;

          }

        
        form{
            position: relative;
            top: 70px;
           
        }
        input{
            padding:10px;
            border-top: 0cm;
            border: 0px;
            width:22em;
            border-radius:5px;
        }
        label{
            color: beige;
            position: relative;
            right:5em;
            bottom: 7px;
            font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-size:1.4em ;
        }
       
       .h{
           font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
          font-size:18px;
          text-transform: uppercase;
         
        }
        .button-71 {
  background-color: #0078d0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 56px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: system-ui,-apple-system,system-ui,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Ubuntu,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  outline: 0;
  padding:30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .3s;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}

.button-71:before {
  background-color: initial;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  border-radius: 125px;
  content: "";
  height: 50%;
  left: 4%;
  opacity: .5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .3s;
  width: 92%;
}

.button-71:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 0 3px 15px inset, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0 3px 5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0 10px 13px;
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .button-71 {
    padding: 18px 58px;
  }
}


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="head"><h3>welcome to sign in page</h3>
        </div><br>

        <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <label for="">Username</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="" id=""><br><br>

            <label for="">Password</label><br>
            <input type="password" name="" id=""><br><br>
            <button class="button-71" role="button">SUBMIT</button>

        </form>

    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Could be a problem with your path to your directory, try with an image url from a website to see if thats the problem, e.g. `background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/536/354");`

Comment: if i am not wrong from your code if pink color image from  https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFOD8.jpg  is your background than use **background-size** property

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines to your body :

```css
          height: 100%;
          background-position: center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: cover;
```

```css
        body{
            
          background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1000);
          height: 100%;
          background-position: center;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: cover;
           
        }
        .container{
          padding: 0;
          margin: auto;
          text-align: center;
          position: relative;
          background-image:url(login.jpg);
          width: 40%;
          height:70vh;
         
          z-index:4;
         
          border-radius: 9px;
        }
          .head h3{
            position: relative;
            top: 60px;
            color: aliceblue;
            font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
            font-size:30px;
            text-transform: capitalize;

          }

        
        form{
            position: relative;
            top: 70px;
           
        }
        input{
            padding:10px;
            border-top: 0cm;
            border: 0px;
            width:22em;
            border-radius:5px;
        }
        label{
            color: beige;
            position: relative;
            right:5em;
            bottom: 7px;
            font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            font-size:1.4em ;
        }
       
       .h{
           font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
          font-size:18px;
          text-transform: uppercase;
         
        }
        .button-71 {
  background-color: #0078d0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 56px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: system-ui,-apple-system,system-ui,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Ubuntu,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  outline: 0;
  padding:30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all .3s;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}

.button-71:before {
  background-color: initial;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  border-radius: 125px;
  content: "";
  height: 50%;
  left: 4%;
  opacity: .5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: all .3s;
  width: 92%;
}

.button-71:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 0 3px 15px inset, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0 3px 5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0 10px 13px;
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .button-71 {
    padding: 18px 58px;
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="head"><h3>welcome to sign in page</h3>
        </div><br>

        <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <label for="">Username</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="" id=""><br><br>

            <label for="">Password</label><br>
            <input type="password" name="" id=""><br><br>
            <button class="button-71" role="button">SUBMIT</button>

        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: i need help in heroku upload code can u plzz help me

Comment: @Plantinumwarrior What are you problem with the upload?

Comment: @MaikLowrey Somebody might come and punish you sooner or later for requesting votes :) Best not to do that.

Comment: @CuteCodeRob You are right. Some people ask for help and take it and say thank you. That is the friendly kind. Then there are people who ask for help and don't say thank you. The unpolite kind. Then there are people who just don't know, but are polite by nature. I think the last one is PlatiumWorrier.

Comment: @Plantinumwarrior I would advise you not to share your phone number here. It's best to create a new question in SO. Ping me then and share the link here in the comment.